# Bounded monotonic sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm having difficulties understanding how to show what sequences are monotonic and/or bounded. I know that a bounded monotonic sequence converges, but what about a sequence that is just monotonic or just bounded? Which ones converge?

I put two problems that I think will help me to understand this concept.

$$\{\frac{(-1)^n}{2n+8} \} = \frac{-1}{10}, \frac{1}{12},\frac{-1}{14},\frac{1}{16},... $$

$$\{tan(\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{1}{k})\} = tan(\frac{\pi}{2}-1),tan(\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{1}{2}),tan(\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{1}{3}), tan(\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{1}{4})$$

Answer (score 2):

It is correct that bounded, monotonic sequences converge. Conversely, convergent sequence are bounded. They are not necessarily monotonic (like your first example).

Sequences which are merely monotonic (like your second example) or merely bounded need not converge.

Answer (score 0):

A bounded or monotonic sequence will not necessarily converge, in general. Take, for instance, the bounded sequence $\{1,-1,1,-1,\ldots\}$, or the monotonic sequence $\{1,2,3,4,\ldots\}$.

Answer (score 0):

If a sequence is convergent, then it has to be bounded. It is not necessarily monotonic.

For instance your example $x_n = \frac{(-1)^n}{2n+8}$ is good for that, as it converges to $0$, and the terms are alternately positive and negative.

The other sequence you have is an example of monotonic sequence which is not bounded (and hence does not converge). It is monotonically increasing and not bounded above ($\frac{\pi}{2} - \frac{1}{n}$ increases to $\frac{\pi}{2}$)

Monotonic, not bounded, and not convergent : $x_n = n$ or $x_n = \tan(\dfrac{\pi}{2} - \dfrac{1}{n})$

Bounded, not monotonic, and not convergent: $x_n = n \mod 2$

Bounded, not monotonic, and convergent: $x_n = \dfrac{(-1)^n}{2n+8}$

Comment: Ok, I get the concept now. But how do I _show_ it?

Comment: @air_wizardo: What does "it" refer to?

Comment: It refers to the problems. Your answer doesn't show how you got to that conclusion.

Comment: @air_wizardo: Are you asking how to prove **all** of the claims that Aryabhata made here? Can you prove any of them on your own?

Comment: @CameronBuie: Not prove, show.

Comment: @air_wizardo: To my mind, those are the same thing. What do you mean by "show," then?

Comment: @CameronBuie: nevermind, i'll ask my professor. thanks anyway